# Connector identification

Tags: dc, connector, identification

[image]

I'm trying to identify this kind of connector, see above. I need to repair it and/or the connector pin. I can't track it down on Digi-Key.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Shopping and repair questions are off-topic on this site. *Possibly* someone here has seen or used that connector before, else it is a shot in the dark.

Comment: You may be able to get some help with this but some more detail will be required. Some key things would be (a) What is this used for? (b) What are the basic dimensions of the connector? (c) What is the pin spacing of the connector?

Comment: show the matching plug if you can ..... people may remember the plug more than the connector on the cable, because they actually have to look at the plug when inserting the connector ..... also show the other two sides of the connector (i assume that the opposite side to this picture looks the same, so no need to repeat it) ..... biggest interest is the  right side as shown in the picture (that would be the underside of the connector)

Comment: There are literally dozens of connectors like this from many manufacturers. Get a vernier caliper and measure the critical dimensions.  Body size, pin pitch and pin hole size.  What does it plug into?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [PAP-02V-S](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/PAP-02V-S/455-1486-ND/759974). It appears to be the connector you are looking for.

[image]